# Javascript inheritance without child.prototype = new parent();

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I was playing around with javascript prototype chain inheritance and i came accross this funny behaviour.

I have a parent class and a child class

```
//class parent
function parent(param_1) {
    this.param_1 = param_1;

    this.getObjWithParam = function(val) {
        console.log(this);
        console.log("Constructor value in parent class " + this.param_1);
        console.log("tguha ----> parent,  val " + val);
    };
};

//class child
function child(param_1) {
    parent.call(this, [ param_1 ]);
};

var childObj = new child(100);
childObj.getObjWithParam(200);
```

and i get the output as

```
**>child**
Constructor value in parent class 100
tguha ----> parent,  val 200
```

and nowhere i'm doing //child.prototype = new parent();
and still the parent class is inherited.

Could anyone help me by explaining this scenario please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word prototype does not appear in this code.  So nothing is being inherited.  You create a new `child` and then explicitly run the `parent` constructor function on that new `child`.  The `parent` constructor function then add a method to to the new `child`.

If you put `getObjWithParam` on `parent.prototype.getObjWithParam` instead then you will see that it will not carry over.

Comment: I had another confusion on the same lines.
this time, i have 3 levels of intheritance and instead of 
`parent.call(this, [ param_1 ]);`
I have 
`this.constructor(param_1);` to pass call to the super class constructor.

I've described the question here few days back.
http://stackoverflow.com/q/8701114/1099211

Probably the same logic could explain the phenomenon that happens there too.

Answer (score 1):

You invoke parent constructor in child constructor. Because parent constructor sets `this.getObjWithParam = function[...]` it'll also set it for child. Notice that this has nothing to do with prototype.
By invoking `parent.call(a, [...])` you invoke parent function and set scope to `a`. That means any modification made to `this` is also made to `a` (because it's the same object).

Answer (score 1):

```
parent.call(this, [ param_1 ])
```

Assigns Parent.param_1 and Parent.getObjWithParam to childObj. This has nothing to do with inheritance. Consider this formulation:

```
var foo = {};

//class parent
function parent(param_1) {
    this.param_1 = param_1;

    this.getObjWithParam = function(val) {
        console.log(this.param_1);
        console.log(val);
    };
};

//class child
function child(param_1) {
    parent.call(foo, [ param_1 ]);
};

var childObj = new child( 'lets give foo a param_1');

console.log( typeof childObj.getObjWithParam );
// Undefined

foo.getObjWithParam();
// ["lets give foo a param_1"]
```

here you are passing foo as a scope to .call() thus the properties are assigned to foo.